# MD5 encoded parameter in URL

Tags: java

I am using following code to encrypt my email id in Java and sending it as a parameter in url (Using URLEncoder.encode(encrypteInput("email"))):

```
public static String encrypteInput(String input) {
        String output = null;
        input = input + ((int) Math.random()) % 1000;
        try {
            MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            output = new String(md5.digest(input.getBytes()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            output = "";
        }
        return output;
}
```

but, when I am getting the same parameter from servlet, it is not giving me the same output as encrypteInput("email").

Comment: How are you getting the parameter from the servlet? Sample?

Comment: same method...String token = request.getParameter("token");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have a byte array that you want to store in a string, you should be Hex- or Base64-encoding the byte array (hex-encoding is probably better in this particular case).

Apache commons-codec has a Hex class you can use for this:

```
byte[] bytes = ...
char[] encoded = Hex.encodeHex(bytes);
String encodedString = new String(encoded);
```

Comment: Okay let me try. Thanks for the help btw

Comment: btw without using any external lib(apache), can I achieve the same ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java